# Trying to create muliple java instances of a java thread but it appears only one is working

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to run two different instances of a Java thread I created, and I see it create the two threads, but only one thread is being called and used at a time. If I run them separately they work fine, but when I try to run the two threads at the same time only one is being updated.

Here is the pertinent code from a main() method:

```
    for( Properties prop: propList){
        Send send = new MainTest().new Send(iterationOffset,prop);
        send.start();
    }      


    public class Send  extends Thread{
      private double iterationOffset;
      private Properties prop;
      SendEsd(double off, Properties p){
        this.iterationOffset = off;
        this.prop = p;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String id = prop.get("platform.id").toString();
            System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ create Thred : send = " +id);
            sendData( iterationOffset,  prop );
        }
      }

      private  void sendData(double iterationOffset, Properties prop ){

        id = prop.get("platform.id").toString();

        // *** the itDataList is a really large CSV it inputs,
        // so it will spin here a long time
        for (it itData : itDataList) {
            try {
              //*** it will send some data here
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("Sleep thread was interrupted.");
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The thread subclass appears to be created only once, and it's not clear what MainClass.new() is.  Can you make sure your code compiles, then post complete classes, or at least complete methods?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.  The correctness of the code you have shown us depends on code that you have not shown us.